# Finding entry with maximum date range between two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Note: this is in Oracle not MySQL, limit/top won't work.

I want to return the name of the person that has stayed the longest in a hotel. The longest stay can be found by subtracting the date in the `checkout` column with the `checkin` column.
So far I have:

```
select fans.name 
from fans 
where fans.checkout-fans.checkin is not null
order by fans.checkout-fans.checkin desc;
```

but this only orders the length of stay of each person from highest to lowest. I want it to only return the name (or names, if they are tied) of people who have stayed the longest. Also, As more than one person could have stayed for the highest length of time, simply adding `limit 1` to the end won't do.

**Edit (for gbn)**, when adding a join to get checkin/checkout from other table it wont work (no records returned)

**edit 2** solved now, the below join should of been `players.team = teams.name`

```
select
   x.name
from
    (
    select
        players.name,
        dense_rank() over (order by teams.checkout-teams.checkin desc) as rnk
    from
        players
    join teams
    on players.name = teams.name
    where
        teams.checkout-teams.checkin is not null
    ) x
where
   x.rnk = 1
```

Comment: MySQL or another platform?

Comment: Oracle, so `limit 1` wouldnt work even if I wanted to use it.

Comment: `players.name = teams.name` doesn't look like a valid join condition.

Comment: @ypercube yes you are right the join was incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be this using [DENSE_RANK to get ties](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dense_rank.php)

```
select
   x.name
from
    (
    select
        fans.name,
        dense_rank() over (order by fans.checkout-fans.checkin desc) as rnk
    from
        fans 
    where
        fans.checkout-fans.checkin is not null
    ) x
where
   x.rnk = 1;
```

SQL Server has [TOP..WITH TIES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9392484/27535) for this, but this is a generic solution for any RDBMS that has DENSE_RANK.

Comment: ... and don't forget that the person with the longest stay might not have checked out yet ;)

Comment: will dense_rank would in oracle?

Comment: @Tangler: yes, why I posted this answer

Comment: i'm getting a `missing right parenthesis` error on this line: `dense_rank() over (fans.checkout-fans.checkin desc) as rnk`

Comment: ok works now, thanks. Your answer is the only correct answer in this thread.

Comment: also, do you know where I would put the `join` if I had to get the check-in/check-out dates from another table first?

Comment: @Tangler: inside the x derived table. Generally, the "outer" select is only to filter on the ranking functions. The "inner" query is written normally but just has a ranking function added

Comment: Please see my updated code above. I've tried adding the join, but it wont return any values.

Comment: @Tangler: check the inner query runs OK first

Comment: using just the inner query also returns no records

Comment: @Tangler: this is a different problem. I can only guess the JOIN is wrong

Comment: yes, should have been players.team, sorry!.. i even checked 3 times and still missed it

Answer (score 0):

Longest is a fuzzy word, you should first define what is long for you. Using limit may not be a solution for this case. So you can define your treshold and try to filter your results `where fans.checkout-fans.checkin > 10` for instance.

Comment: by longest i mean the the person that stayed at a hotel for the highest amount of days (i.e. `checkout-checkin` as these are date fields)

Comment: Then you can use Rank function, see here : http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name, (checkout-checkin) AS stay
from fans 
where stay is not null -- remove fans that never stayed at a hotel
order by stay desc;
```

Comment: I don't want it to print the length of stay, only the name of the person. I also only want to print the person or persons that stayed the longest.

Answer (score 0):

**For Oracle:**

```
select * from 
(
select fans.name
from fans 
where fans.checkout-fans.checkin is not null
order by fans.checkout-fans.checkin desc)
where rownum=1
```

Comment: what if two people are tied for longest stay?

Answer (score 0):

Another way that should work in all dbms (or almost all, at least those that support subqueries):

```
select fans.name 
from fans 
where fans.checkout-fans.checkin = 
      ( select max(f.checkout-f.checkin) 
        from fans f
      ) ;
```

Comment: Yes, it will. I think @gbn's will be more efficient though and easier to alter if you have joins included. In this answer, if the checkout, checkin dates and the names come from joins, you'll have to alter both the external query and the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If both the columns are date fields you can use this query:

`select fans.name  from fans  where fans.checkout-fans.checkin in (select max(fans.checkout-fans.checkin) from fans );`